# name ... not defined, Python

Tags: python-3.x

so, I' written a Python program, wich takes user input and goes trough some options. 
You can see the code here:

```
#Bereiche
bereiche = input("Welchen Bereich wollen sie betreten?\nDie Optionen sind: Formeln, Rechnen,\n")
#Formeln
if bereiche == "Formeln":
    formel = input("welche Art von Formel wollen sie outputen?\nDie Optionen sind: Flächeninhalte, Umfänge, Physikalische,\n")
#Rechenarten
if bereiche == "Rechnen":
    rechnen = input("Welche Rechenart wollen sie vollführen?\nFlächeninhalte, Umfänge, Physikalische, Funktionen\n") #Gleichungen

#Flächeninhalte
if rechnen == "Flächeninhalte":
    A_art = input("Flächeninhalt welches Objekts?\nOptionen sind: Rechtecke, Quadrate, Kreise,\n")
#Rechteck
if A_art == "Rechteck":
    Höhe = input("Höhe des Rechtecks:")
    Länge = input("Länge des Rechtecks:")
    A_recht = float(Höhe)*float(Länge)
    print(A_recht)
#Quadrate
if A_art == "Quadrate":
    Länge = input("Länge des Quadrats:")
    A_quad = float(A_quad)*float(A_quad)
    print(A_quad)
#Kreise
pi = 3.141592654
if A_art == "Kreise" and rechnen == "Flächeninhalte":
    radius = input("Radius des Kreises:")
    A_kreis = float(radius)*float(radius)*float(pi)
    print(A_kreis)

#Umfänge
if rechnen == "Umfänge":
    U_art = input("Welche Art von Umfang?\nOptionen sind: Rechtecke, Quadrate, Kreise")
```

My problem is at line 19 if my Input for "rechnen" isn`t "Flächeninhalte".
The error IDLE gave out is the following: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/Desktop/Mathe.py", line 19, in 
    if A_art == "Rechteck" and rechnen == "Flächeninhalte":
NameError: name 'A_art' is not defined

How can I fix this problem? 
Thanks for any help in advance

Ps: Sorry for the part-german code, it`s kinda meant for my school

Comment: What will happen if `rechnen` is not equal to `Flächeninhalte`? What will be a value of `A_art` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initiated the variable. At some point near the beginning of your program do `A_art = 'null'` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Change this Case:

```
 A_art=None
 if rechnen == "Flächeninhalte":
      A_art = input("Flächeninhalt welches Objekts?\nOptionen sind:Rechtecke, Quadrate, Kreise,\n")
```